# How can I execute jquery animate scroll after page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I have a bootstrap 3 navbar in rails 4 with a logo on it. When the document is ready it runs:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("html,body").animate
    scrollTop: 270
  , "slow"
```

This properly aligns the top image in the browser.

If I click the logo in the navbar, it will scroll to the top of the page with this code:

```
  $("#home").click (e)->
    e.preventDefault()
    $("html,body").animate
      scrollTop: 270
    , "slow"
```

If, however, I click on a different navbar item (say "about me") and then click on the logo, it loads the home page but it does not scroll to the proper position.

How can I ensure that the page scrolling occurs reliably every time I load the page so that the photo is always aligned initially?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Todd was absolutely right that changing .ready to .on "page:change" was a key to solving this issue. The completed will scroll to the default position or the scroll-down-link position when the links are clicked. Thanks!

```
$(document).on "page:change", (e)->
    if $("#intro").length
        e.preventDefault()
        $("html,body").animate
        scrollTop: 270
      , "slow"

        $("#home").click (e)->
            e.preventDefault()
            $("html,body").animate
                scrollTop: 270
            , "slow"


    $("#scroll-down-link").click (e)->
        e.preventDefault()
        $("html,body").animate
            scrollTop: 1300
        , "slow"
```

Comment: can you put code into a jsfiddle; I may have answered incorrectly for not having understood the exact issue well

Comment: without an animated gif or js fiddle, it's very unlikely somebody will give correct answer.

Comment: Hey Todd, you are absolutely right.  It is a little tricky to get jsfiddle working with a bootstrap app but for what it is worth, I am pretty sure that the issue I am running into is turbolinks related.  It appears as if rails doesn't fire off the $(document).ready after the page loads because of turbolinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turbo links wont trigger the ready event, so you have to use the 'page:change' event instead. It's detailed [HERE](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks). it works this way because turbo links override the normal page loading process.

do:

```
$(document).on 'page:change', ->
```

non-coffeescript version

```
$(document).on('page:change', function() {


});
```